# Pucher выдает client error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, push-уведомления

как решить данную проблему?

```
{"event":"client-typing","data":{"name":"Mouse"},"channel":"private-chat.21"}
{"event":"pusher:error","data":{"code":null,"message":"To send client events, you must enable this feature in the Settings page of your dashboard."}}
```

хочу вывести сообщение, что пользователь набирает текст

```
actionUser(){
    window.Echo.private('chat.' + this.dialogSelect)
        .whisper('typing', {
            name: this.userAuth.fullname
        });
},

window.Echo.private('chat.' + this.dialogSelect)
  .listen('DialogMessage',({data}) => {
          this.messages.push(data);
          this.isTyping = false;
  })
  .listenForWhisper('typing', (e) => {
      console.log(e);
      this.isTyping = e;
      if (this.typingTimer) clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
      this.typingTimer = setTimeout(() => {
          this.isTyping = false;
      }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Допер, поставил в настройках на сайте pusher Enable client events